# Generate test data bulkly in drupal 8

Tags: 8, debugging

I setup a website based on Drupal8,create some content type(with several fields),Now I want to enter some test data in my site.
**How can I generate test data bulky in drupal8?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devel module will Do it for you and happy Devel module is ported to Drupal 8 https://www.drupal.org/project/devel

Enable Devel and Devel Generate

go to "`/admin/config/development/generate/content`" give the number of content it will generate bulk content for you.

Comment: but when I have video file `Error: Class 'Drupal\video\Plugin\Field\FieldType\Random' not found in Drupal\video\Plugin\Field\FieldType\VideoItem::generateSampleValue() (line 1` .